# How to render component for some routes in React Navigation v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a global component that I need to show only for some routes. How can I do that? I use only stack navigators.

```js
const route = useRoute();

if (route.name !== 'Main') return null;
```

It doesn't work.

**UPD**. Question is actual. If somebody has an idea, please tell.